# How to copy and paste certain text into a CERTAIN line in Python?

Tags: python, shutil

Alright, there are so many posts about copying and pasting text into a file, but I want to add it to a SPECIFIC line inside of the code that I'm pasting it into.

For example, I have this file named 'main.leap' and the contents look exactly like this:

```
outln "Hello";
```

And I have another file named 'main.py' and the contents look exactly like this:

```
text_input = """

"""

print(text_input)
```

How can I use imports like Shutil to paste the contents of main.leap SPECIFICALLY inside line 2 and in no other line?

Comment: Why using imports like shutil? It would be easier without that.

Answer (score 0):

Without shutil:

```py
main = open('main.py')
lines = main.readlines()
main.close()

leap = open('main.leap')
newline = leap.read()
leap.close()

lines.insert(1, newline)

main = open('main.py', 'w')
main.writelines(lines)
main.close()
```

Comment: Do I change the 1 to 2 for the second line?

Comment: @gamermerch nope, it counts 0, 1, 2, 3...  so 1 is the second.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I completely copied the code you told me to use. When it prints out, nothing comes out, except a bunch of blank spaces.

Comment: That's not enough information to tell what's happening from here; maybe add some `print()` statements into it so you can see what it's doing; `print(lines)` and `print(newline)` and `printe(lines)` again after the change, see if it's reading the files, see if it's reading the right files, see if it's inserting the line, see if it's inserting the line in the right place, etc.